# MooTools: How to tell if object is array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mootools

Is there a shortcut in MooTools for telling if an object is an object or an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MooTools has a $type(), where you pass in an object.

```
var myString = 'hello';
$type(myString);
```

You can find more information at http://mootools.net/docs/core#type

Comment: In the latest version of Mootools this function is now called `typeOf`: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#Core:typeOf

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about MooTools, but you could check with Javascript:

```
var someObject = [];
console.log(someObject instanceof Array) // logs true
```

But since an array is also an object, you'd have to check if it's an Array first before checking for Object. But using the `$type` method is probably easier.

**Edit**:

Mootools provides a $type function that gives the type of an object:

Tests ran:

```
console.log($type("hello"));​​​​​
console.log($type(new Object()));
console.log($type([1, 2, 3]));
​
```

Output:

```
string
object
array
```

Try it before you buy it at http://mootools.net/shell/

Found the info from this article - http://javascript-reference.info/useful-utility-functions-in-mootools.htm

Comment: The `instanceof` check will return `false` for an array that has come from another window or frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with native JavaScript:

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(value ) === '[object Array]'
```

[Source:  The Miller Device](http://profiles.yahoo.com/blog/GSBHPXZFNRM2QRAP3PXNGFMFVU?eid=fam48bo6nChhLpXTWLYuo2PoctbJjTIo34SjoLBF9VV3glXt.w)

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.3.2 and above you can use the `typeOf` [function](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.3.2/Core/Core#Core:typeOf), there is also a shorter and more sementic shortcut using the `Type` object:

```js
// syntax Type.is[type]

Type.isArray(['foo', 'bar']); // true
```